# Deleting entries from arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2019

I wrote a program to delete a certain element from an array but it doesn't seem to work as I intended and I can't spot the error here. I'm aware it is kind of a simple issue but I would like to know why the output is as such.

Here is the code itself:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int numList[30], sizeofArray, deleteElement, i, j, k, a, b;
    printf("Please specify the number of entries: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &sizeofArray);

    printf("\nPlease initialize the list with %d entries: ",sizeofArray);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeofArray; i++)
        scanf_s("%d", &numList[i]);
    printf("\nInitial values in the array are: ");
    for (j = 0; j < sizeofArray; j++)
        printf("%d ", numList[j]);

    printf("\nPlease specify the element you want to delete: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &deleteElement);
    for (k = 0; k < sizeofArray; k++) {
        if (deleteElement == numList[k]) {
            for (a = k; a < sizeofArray - 1; a++);
                numList[a] = numList[a+1];
            k--;
            sizeofArray--;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe updated list contains the elements: ");
    for (b = 0; b < sizeofArray; b++)
        printf("%d ", numList[b]);
}
```

And the output is:

Please specify the number of entries: 6

Please initialize the list with 6 entries: 20 9 4 9 9 33

Initial values in the array are: 20 9 4 9 9 33

Please specify the element you want to delete: 9

The updated list contains the elements: 20

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about c++? This looks like c to me.

Comment: Try and declare variables as close as possible to where they're used, like `for (int b = 0; ...)` is preferable to `int b` and then many,  many lines later `for (b = 0; ...)` It makes it easier to understand and debug.

Comment: You have an extra `;` after your `for (a` loop.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you kindly. I didn't pay attention to that

Comment: Once you find the element, you need to break out of the loop.

Comment: @tadman I did that initially but I changed it afterwards and declared all the loop variables at the beginning. I will pay more attention to it though, thank you.

Comment: @stark I understand what you are trying to say but I'm trying to delete all entries equal to the one the user enters. Not just the first one that occurs.

Comment: @rev If you want to remove elements, there are ways in C++ of doing this in two or three lines of code, not loops upon loops.  The `std::remove` function works for arrays.

Comment: Don't do `i, j, k, a, b;` to yourself. Definitely don't do it to other people. First make sure you need the variable, and if you do give them descriptive names.

Comment: @rev -- You tagged this as `C++`, and here is the way you would do this in C++. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71ae96c3e22c2bd3).  Now, are you still willing to stick with basically `C` coding, or use C++?

Comment: @user4581301 I'm aware. It was just a quick exercise.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am going to stick with C probably since this is the language we are using in my college. As for how this could be done in a few lines, I guessed that would be the case but this was something my professor wrote (I'm a freshman so we deal with very basic things) and so I wanted to try and run it myself. By the way, thank you for the example.

Comment: How do you determine if an element in the array is deleted?  What value can you use to mark an element as deleted? See `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care about preserving the input list, you can do this is an single loop:

```
int writer = 0;
for (int reader = 0; reader < sizeofArray; ++reader) 
     if (numList[reader] != deleteElement)
         numList[writer++] = numList[reader];
sizeofArray = writer;
```

`reader` walks the array. `writer` keeps track of where to append the next value. You only update `writer` when the value does not match `deleteElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with your code:

1. **Already specify array size**: if you already declare `numList` to have 30 elements, then you can no longer change its size, making `sizeOfArray` useless. Try first asking for `sizeOfArray` as input and *then* declaring `numList[sizeOfArray]`.
2. **Deleting elements in fixed-size array**: as I said, once you specify the size of an array, you can no longer change it. This means 'deleting' an element doesn't really mean anything. You are just shifting all values back by one slot and leaving the second-to-last element equal to the last one. This is only solved by using, as mentioned in the comments, containers of variable size like an `std::vector`.

Btw this is C, not C++!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to replace snippet A with snippet B.

A:

```
for (k = 0; k < sizeofArray; k++)
{
    if (deleteElement == numList[k]) {
        for (a = k; a < sizeofArray - 1; a++);
        numList[a] = numList[a + 1];
        k--;
        sizeofArray--;
    }
}
   printf("\nThe updated list contains the elements: ");
    for (b = 0; b < sizeofArray; b++)
        printf("%d ", numList[b]);
```

B:

```
   for (k = 0; k <sizeofArray; k++)
    {
        if (deleteElement == numList[k]) delectIndex = k;//the index of the element to delete

    }

    for (k = delectIndex; k <sizeofArray - 1; k++)
    {
        numList[k] = numList[k + 1];

    }
    printf("\nThe updated list contains the elements: ");
    for (i = 0; i < sizeofArray-1 ; i++)
    {
       printf("%4d", numList[i]);
    }
```

This code looks for an element in an array and returns the position index. If an element is found, the index is returned (If there are multiple identical elements, only the position of the last element is returned). And then remove elements from the array based on position index.